# PHP - Creating a comma separated list within foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I was able to group an array by a common key using `foreach` now I am looking to take further and create a comma delimited list and each try results in a list but with no commas; they are either getting removed or I am not doing this right.

```
$families = array();
foreach($results as $key => $item) {
    $families[$item['family_id']][] = $item;
}

Array (
    [54] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 54
                    [firstname] => Adam
                    [primary] => 1
                )
        )
    [89] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 89
                    [firstname] => Alex
                    [primary] => 1
                )
        )
    [44] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 44
                    [firstname] => Anne-Marie
                    [primary] => 1
                )
        )
    [282] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 282
                    [firstname] => Ashley
                    [primary] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 282
                    [firstname] => Leah
                    [primary] => 
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 282
                    [firstname] => Brad
                    [primary] => 
                )
        )
    [292] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [family_id] => 292
                    [firstname] => Brenda
                    [primary] => 1
                )
        )
    )
```

The end result is a `foreach` the generates the following list of families with children.

Family: Adam
Family: Alex
Family: Anne-Marie
Family: Ashley
Children: Leah, Brad
Family: Brenda

```
foreach($families as $family) {
  foreach($family as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value['primary'])) {
      $children = array('firstname' => $value['firstname']);
      $child = implode(', ', $children);
    }
    if (!empty($value['primary'])) {
      echo 'Family: '.$value['firstname'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code which try to output the expected result ?

Comment: Where is the code, which tries to output comma separated list?

Comment: Sorry, had to put it back as I was on to trying some other solution - still not getting it and it may just be two many arrays or foreach in my code that is causing my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get parents first, then children, into separate arrays

```
foreach ($families as $family) {
    $parents = array_map(function ($person) {
        return $person['firstname'];
    }, array_filter($family, function ($person) {
        return !empty($person['primary']);
    }));

    $children = array_map(function ($person) {
        return $person['firstname'];
    }, array_filter($family, function ($person) {
        return empty($person['primary']);
    }));


    if (count($parents)) {
        echo 'Family : ' . implode(',', $parents) . '<br />';
    }

    if (count($children)) {
        echo 'Children : ' . implode(',', $children) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

The array_filter, help us to exclude the non wanted data while the array_map allow us to perform a function on each array element : returning the firstname for example.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking to get and it worked like a charm, there is other data and formatting I want to draw in and should be able to walk through your example to get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Extra data and formatting added and it works like a charm! Many thanks again!